# Different XML for bible, any standard?

Tags: xml, open-source

Is there any *de facto* **open standard** for formatting the bible?
So far I found 3 different xml format:

- [OSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Scripture_Information_Standard)
- [ThMl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theological_Markup_Language)
- [Zefania XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zefania_XML)

Both **ThMl** and **ZefaniaXML** seem only used by their designer. **OSIS** is totally dead.
I know the SWORD Project, which offers great tools and seems widely used, but it uses a proprietary compression routine, so I don’t know the raw format behind, and can’t deal with custom translation.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect any serious scholarly project these days to be using TEI. See for example the International Greek New Testament Project at http://www.igntp.org

But that's all about scholarly publication, comparison of alternative sources, analysis of translations, etc. If what you're after is producing an app for mobile devices for use by the man-in-the-pew, then you might want something quite different.

The Digital Bible Project uses its own format called USX, which might be closer to your needs:

https://thedigitalbiblelibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/AboutDBL-ProductSummary.pdf

http://www.thedigitalbiblelibrary.org/static/docs/usx/index.html